# PrimeSense webcam settings for ARToolKit Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, openni, artoolkit

My Windows 10 laptop has a Unity Project which uses the Integrated Webcam for an [ARToolKit](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_video_capture) package.

Unity Inspector default package settings:
[image: Unity Inspector default pkg settings]

What settings do I need to instead use a PrimeSense (Kinect-like, [OpenNI2](http://com.occipital.openni.s3.amazonaws.com/OpenNI_Programmers_Guide.pdf) Structure Sensor) camera attached via USB?

Device Manager for Dell Inspiron 15R:

[image: Device Manager for Dell Inspiron 15R]

Comment: ideally Structure Sensor would be accessible via HTML5's `.getUserMedia()` (on iOS at the very least)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I screencaptured the sensor's viewer application (NiViewer), saved the (TinyTake) capture as an .mp4, converted to a .mov (Any Video Converter), and used ARToolKit's "QuickTime Video Input from Movie File or Stream" directions. I changed `Video config. (Windows)` to

`-device=QUICKTIME -movie=“file:///C:/path/to/captured movie.mov”`